# Flags in global Stack config.yaml

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I tried adding some flags to my global Stack `config.yaml`:

```
flags:
  extra-include-dirs: /usr/include/
```

Alas it's not being recognised:

```
Warning: /Users/vilem/.stack/config.yaml: Unrecognized field in ConfigMonoid: flags
```

What am I doing wrong? The documentation doesn't seem to have an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer—just add this:

```
extra-include-dirs:
  - /usr/include/
```

It would still be nice to be able to pass global flags to Stack.