# How to set a "global" package flag using stack (haskell)?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I need to invoke stack as such on Mac OSX (other team members are using Linux, so we can't add this to our `stack.yaml`):

```
stack build --flag hlibsass:externallibsass
```

Is there any way to add it to my `~/.stack/config.yaml` so that this is picked up as a default flag whenever I'm compilng any stack project locally on my machine? I tried adding it, but got the following error. Is there any way to do this via `ghc-options`, or any other way?

```
Warning: /Users/saurabhnanda/.stack/config.yaml: Unrecognized field in ConfigMonoid: flags
```

Related: [Flags in global Stack config.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502136/flags-in-global-stack-config-yaml)